# Should I add .swiftpm to gitignore?

Tags: git, swift-package-manager

A .swiftpm directory is created when editing a Swift Package in Xcode. Should I ignore this directory by adding to my .gitignore?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/files-created-when-opening-spm-package-in-xcode-11/28589/2) in the Swift forums, the `.swiftpm` directory "is intended as a place for tools that operate on packages to store state or configuration files of their own that users are not expected to edit directly as source" - it is not exclusive to Xcode support. So to add it to .gitignore could potentially have a bigger impact than just ignoring Xcode files.

You could consider ignoring `.swiftpm/xcode` instead, but thats also not universally recommended, because Xcode stores shared schemes there, as was mentioned in this [rejected pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2209).

By default, Swift Package Manager adds `xcuserdata/` to the [.gitignore](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/0d31fb5b9ca4675ee3e95f2db43e7fb4faeb8066/Sources/Workspace/InitPackage.swift#L174-L181), which is the primary ignore you need for using SPM with Xcode.

Comment: I spent hours wondering why my CI wouldn't work having a misterious xcodebuild and git error like so `xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:` ... `fatal: Needed a single revision` It was indeed happenning because the schemes created by xcode (in `.swiftpm/xcode/`) wouldn't be add/commit to the repository... Finally found the problem -_- choose wisely what to ignore and be curious is the lesson here.

Comment: Interestingly, [Apple's Swift Package Manager Project](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager) itself does seem to include the full `.swiftpm` directory in its own gitignore file (https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/.gitignore#L14).

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Don't ignore swiftpm, check it in.

The swiftpm directory stores which version of a package dependency you are using (in Package.resolved) when using Swift Package Manager (SPM).

In the following link Apple mentions this is particularly important if you're working with a team so you are all using the same version of that package: ["Commit this file in Git to ensure that everyone is using the same version of a package dependency."](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-package-dependencies-to-your-app#Coordinate-package-versions-across-your-team)

*Note: If you open Package.resolved you'll see it has the same package version information you find in Xcode's Project navigator under Package Dependencies:*

[image: Show Package Contents of Xcode project]

---

[image: Show Package Contents of workspace]

---

[image: Open Package.resolved]

---

```
{
  "pins" : [
    {
      "identity" : "abseil-cpp-swiftpm",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/firebase/abseil-cpp-SwiftPM.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "583de9bd60f66b40e78d08599cc92036c2e7e4e1",
        "version" : "0.20220203.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "boringssl-swiftpm",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/firebase/boringssl-SwiftPM.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "dd3eda2b05a3f459fc3073695ad1b28659066eab",
        "version" : "0.9.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "firebase-ios-sdk",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "7e80c25b51c2ffa238879b07fbfc5baa54bb3050",
        "version" : "9.6.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "googleappmeasurement",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "c1cfde8067668027b23a42c29d11c246152fe046",
        "version" : "9.6.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "googledatatransport",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/google/GoogleDataTransport.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "7874c1b48cbffd086ce8a052c4be873a78613775",
        "version" : "9.2.3"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "googleutilities",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/google/GoogleUtilities.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "871d43135925cde39ef7421d8723ce47edfdcc39",
        "version" : "7.11.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "grpc-ios",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/grpc/grpc-ios.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "8440b914756e0d26d4f4d054a1c1581daedfc5b6",
        "version" : "1.44.3-grpc"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "gtm-session-fetcher",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "5ccda3981422a84186387dbb763ba739178b529c",
        "version" : "2.3.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "leveldb",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/firebase/leveldb.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "0706abcc6b0bd9cedfbb015ba840e4a780b5159b",
        "version" : "1.22.2"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "nanopb",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/firebase/nanopb.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "819d0a2173aff699fb8c364b6fb906f7cdb1a692",
        "version" : "2.30909.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "promises",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/google/promises.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "ec957ccddbcc710ccc64c9dcbd4c7006fcf8b73a",
        "version" : "2.2.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "swift-protobuf",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "0af9125c4eae12a4973fb66574c53a54962a9e1e",
        "version" : "1.21.0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "version" : 2
}
```

---

[image: Xcode Project navigator Package Dependencies]

Answer (score -1):

Whether you choose to add `.swiftpm` to your `.gitignore` file will depend on whether you want your collaborators to checkout the files in the `.swiftpm` directory.

So long as the contents of the `.swiftpm` directory only consist of Xcode project settings and development of your Swift Package does not necessitate the use of Xcode you can add `.swiftpm` to your `.gitignore` if you choose. Whether you should choose to do so or not, however, will depend on your personal preferences regarding what you consider to be the best practice for maintaining code hygiene.